# TopShelf service stops unexpected

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, topshelf

I have implemented a windows service using TopShelf. The service hosts some WCF services that can be consumed by clients, one of them uses IBM MQ.

Usually the service runs normal as expected. But sometimes the service just stops while processing a request as if anyone regularly stopped it. The event logs only shows errors that are caused **by** the stop,

```
Failed to stop service. System.InvalidOperationException: An unhandled exception was detected ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at IBM.WMQ.MQFAPConnection.AsyncFailureNotify(Exception ex, Boolean quiescing)
at IBM.WMQ.MQRcvThread.Run
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ConctextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ConctextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ConctextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at TopShelf.Runtime.Windows.Windows.ServiceHost.OnStop()
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.DeferredStop()
```

I have tried several ways to force such a situation such as raising Exceptions in tasks, raising exceptions in the WCF service implementation, raising CSEs, etc. None of them caused a "regular" stop of the service.

Comment: Looking at the callstack, OnStop is called .As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop(v=vs.110).aspx)  `When implemented in a derived class, executes when a Stop command is sent to the service by the Service Control Manager (SCM). Specifies actions to take when a service stops running.` .So it does look like a stop command is sent.Do you have more callstack

Comment: Also Please check if any event is logged by the Servicec control manager in the event logs https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349442(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Apologies for the late response. It seems that the farm where the process is tricking us. The SCM does not reveal anything unexpected, as far as we know by now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same here. Topshelf in combination with IBM MQ causes problems. [See here for more information](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/366)